# Open Firewall for Remote WMI

Tags: vba, windows-firewall

I currently use `winrs` and `shell` to change the firewall rules on a remote PC so I can query WMI.

```
strCMD = "winrs -r:" & strHost & " netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group=" _
         & Chr(34) & "Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)" & Chr(34) _
         & " new enable=yes"
Shell "cmd.exe /S /C" & strCMD, vbMinimizedNoFocus
```

Is there a better way to do this that won't pop up CMD windows which briefly steal the focus?

---

Expanding on my issue:
My team leaders are not the most tech savvy people, so I am creating a bunch of macros in an Excel workbook that will allow them to do various things (like toggling between USB Storage enabled/disabled, or temporarily elevating the user to a local admin, etc.). Everything works, but my team leads are annoyed by the fact that when they run a command, a CMD window pops up and briefly takes the focus (even though I specify `vbMinimizedNoFocus`). I'm not aware of another way to open the firewall so they can perform various tasks when they are merely local admins and not domain admins. Is there an API or COM object or something I can reference in VBA to remotely change firewall settings? Or is there another method for calling `Shell`...like perhaps `WScript.Shell` that would work without a CMD window popping up?

Comment: Yep. My bad. Not sure how I made that mistake in tags. xD Going to edit the question to expand on the issue I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the `WScript.Shell` object's [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method instead of the `Shell` function should work:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "cmd.exe /S /C " & strCMD, 0, True
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Exactly what I was looking for. :)